# Schwarz–Christoffel implies Riemann mapping theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

we know that the Schwarz-Christoffel formula for polygons appeared after the Riemann mapping theorem, as mentioned here at page 13 https://asset-pdf.scinapse.io/prod/567060304/567060304.pdf

The author also said that it is possible to prove the RM theorem with use of the SC formula. Is there any literature? Thank you!

Comment: Presumably the author meant the results such as [Hertling (1997,1999)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397598002904/pdf?md5=5e0642d2f367d4b81f601ff43748e95c&amp;pid=1-s2.0-S0304397598002904-main.pdf&amp;_valck=1) allowing an exhaustion of your domain $\Omega$ using polygonal domains $\Omega_n$ with rational coordinates ($\Omega=\bigcup\Omega_n$).  So you have a constructive proof of RMT by computing the SC mapping of polygon $f_n\colon\mathbb{D}\to\Omega_n$ and take limit to get the Riemann map $f\colon\mathbb{D}\to\Omega$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for your answer! Tbh I can't really see where Hertling try to use an approximation by polygons. Can you tell me the page?

Comment: Hertling didn't use polygonal approximation but something similar to Koebe iteration instead.  I'm just referring to the corollary of being recursively enumerable open that you can obtain constructible/computable polygonal approximations $\Omega_1\subset\Omega_2\subset\dots\subset\Omega$ with $d_H(\Omega_n,\Omega)<2^{-n}$, for example.  If you don't care about computability then of course this approximation result is known much earlier.

Comment: @user10354138 Great, that's what I'm looking for! Do you know a source with a proof of this polygonal approximation? :))